# php.exe (WAMP) cannot allocate more than 1G memory, even with memory _limit set to -1

Tags: php, windows, symfony, memory, composer-php

Since a few days, I cannot update my Symfony projects using Composer because the php.exe process from my WAMP install cannot allocate more than 1G of memory... I don't recall making any changes in my PHP settings.

In the php.ini (yes, the correct one), I've set memory_limit to -1. My composer diagnose is all set to OK.

- My PHP version is 5.6.18
- My WAMP version is 3.1.3
- My OS is Windows 7
- My Composer version is 1.6.5

Could it come from a Windows setting?

Here is the error message I get :

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1397751808) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/wamp/www/DESiwid/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
Segmentation fault
```

I have the same kind of error with a PHP test standalone script that I have coded to allocate :

```
set memory_limit to 810M
memory limit is 810M
try allocating 800 megabyte...pass.Usage: 800.5 Peak: 800.5
memory_limit (get value):849346560
set memory_limit to 860M
memory limit is 860M
try allocating 850 megabyte...pass.Usage: 850.5 Peak: 850.5
memory_limit (get value):901775360
set memory_limit to 910M
memory limit is 910M
try allocating 900 megabyte...pass.Usage: 900.5 Peak: 900.5
memory_limit (get value):954204160
set memory_limit to 960M
memory limit is 960M
try allocating 950 megabyte...
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 996147201 bytes
) in C:\wamp\www\_test\memory.php on line 5
```

Comment: I have this problem days ago, i fixed pass my symfony project to PHP 7

Comment: @JassonRojas then you also upgraded WAMP to a PHP7 version ? 32 bits or 64 ?

Comment: in effect when i search so much i found two solutions, one is upgrade your xampp to 64 bits version but if that dont works you have to   install PHP on your windows manually. first download the php version that you want to use form here: https://windows.php.net/download/. Then you have to extract the folder and add the folder to enviroment variables of your pc (Be sure than remove the Xampp php version from envirament variables) and thats it. For me the second solutions works like a charm ! Hope it works !

Comment: I'll try this then... I had a feeling that this could be related to the 32bits version of WAMP that I use yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution : I was using WAMP 32bits, and switched to WAMP 64bits, that solved everything.